# How can I wait for a download to complete?

Tags: html, flutter, flutter-web

In a Flutter web app, when a button is tapped, I want to download a file and then show a confirmation snackbar:

```
onTap: () async {
      saveSettings(artWork);
      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(
         backgroundColor: Colors.green,
         content: Text('Artwork has been saved. File name: ${artWork.title + ".diy"}')));
      Navigator.pop(context);}
```

where saveSettings() looks like this:

```
void saveSettings(ArtWork artWork) {
  Uint8List pngBytes = encodeArt(artWork);
  Blob blob = Blob([pngBytes], 'application/octet-stream');
  String fileName = artWork.title + '.diy';
  AnchorElement anchor = AnchorElement(
    href: Url.createObjectUrlFromBlob(blob),
  );
  anchor.setAttribute("download", fileName);
  anchor.click();
}
```

The web browser (Safari on iPad, Chrome on Windows) then asks the user if/where they want to download the file. My problem is that the confirmation snackbar is shown directly, even if the user rejects the download.

How can I wait for the download to complete?